# How to build json dynamically in python using tuple

Tags: json, python-3.x

I want to build json in following format

```
{
           "codeTableData":
           [
               {
               "codeValue": "11",
               "codeDisplayName": "AAAAAA"
               },
               {
               "codeValue": "22",
               "codeDisplayName": "BBBBBB"
               }
           ]
}
```

from tuple which is

```
result = [('11', 'AAAAAA'), ('22', 'BBBBBB'), ('33', 'CCCCCCCC')]
```

I have tried creating dictionary and then adding tuple data inside that dictionary but still no luck

```
jsonResult = {"codeTableData: " [
                              {
                                tmp1:tmp2
                              },
                          ]}
            json_data = json.dumps(jsonResult)
```

for above code program execution comes out of function with no error shown

Answer (score 1):

You can construct a list of dictionaries with:

```
json_data = json.dumps(
    {'codeTableData':
     [{'codeValue': cv, 'codeDisplayName': cn} for cv, cn in result]}
)
```

We thus iterate over the list of 2-tuples, and for each item, we add a dictionary that maps `'codeValue'` to the first item and `codeDisplayName` to the second item.

We can make use of `zip` as well:

```
column_names = ['codeValue', 'codeDisplayName']
json_data = json.dumps(
    {'codeTableData': [dict(zip(column_names, data)) for data in result]}
)
```

Comment: Hi Wilem Van Onsem you saved my ass Its worked eaxctly as I wanted. I want to know is there any article which explains how to construct json dynamically in Python

Comment: @epoi: It has not that much to do with JSON itself, that is just the target encoding. It here uses list comprehension https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python to construct Python objects that are then converted to JSON.

Comment: Or look at the official [python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#data-structures)

Answer (score 1):

Try code below, hope it will help.

```
results = [('11', 'AAAAAA'), ('22', 'BBBBBB'), ('33', 'CCCCCCCC')]

column_names = ['codeValue', 'codeDisplayName']

data = [ {key:data for key,data in zip(column_names,result) } for result in results ]
```

Ouput of this would be:

```
[{'codeValue': '11', 'codeDisplayName': 'AAAAAA'}, {'codeValue': '22', 'codeDisplayName': 'BBBBBB'}, {'codeValue': '33', 'codeDisplayName': 'CCCCCCCC'}]
```

For converting the data into json, as required use below code.

```
json.dumps({'code_data': [ {key:data for key,data in zip(column_names,result) } for result in results ]})
```

Now output would be:

```
{"code_data": [{"codeValue": "11", "codeDisplayName": "AAAAAA"}, {"codeValue": "22", "codeDisplayName": "BBBBBB"}, {"codeValue": "33", "codeDisplayName": "CCCCCCCC"}]}
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it just like:

```
result = [('11', 'AAAAAA'), ('22', 'BBBBBB'), ('33', 'CCCCCCCC')]

data_json = {"codeTableData":[]}

for item in result:
    data_json["codeTableData"].append({"codeValue":item[0],"codeDisplayName":item[1]})

print (data_json)
```

output:

```
{'codeTableData': [{'codeValue': '11', 'codeDisplayName': 'AAAAAA'}, {'codeValue': '22', 'codeDisplayName': 'BBBBBB'}, {'codeValue': '33', 'codeDisplayName': 'CCCCCCCC'}]}
```